# How do I get the paragraph to be directly under H5 and not beside it?

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of coding my portfolio, and I'm having trouble with the H5 and paragraphs. Right now, the paragraphs are next to the H5, which is not what I want. I want the H5 to be horizontal, and the paragraph text to be positioned directly below the headings in a horizontal arrangement. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
     <section class="ui-design">
        <h2>UI-design</h2>
        <p>Designing a new website</p>
        <div class="article-container">
          <article>
            <h5>Client:</h5>
            <p>Småtrollens föräldrakooperativ</p>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h5>Duration:</h5>
            <p>2 weeks</p>
          </article>
          <article>
            <h5>Team:</h5>
            <p>Isabelle, Rebecca, Måns & Pontus</p>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>e
```

CSS

```
.ui-design {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3%;
}

.ui-design h2, .ui-design h5 {
  color: black;
}


.article-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
}

article {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ui-design h2, .ui-design h5 {
  color: black;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .article-container {
    flex-direction: row; 
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rOfX.png)

Comment: Child elements of `article` are being in-lined because of the `display: flex` without `flex-direction: column`. `h2` and `p` would be block elements by default if you just removed the flex rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the display behaviour of the `article` to `block` instead of `flex`:

```css
.ui-design {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3%;
}

.ui-design h2,
.ui-design h5 {
  color: black;
}

.article-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.ui-design h2,
.ui-design h5 {
  color: black;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .article-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="ui-design">
  <h2>UI-design</h2>
  <p>Designing a new website</p>
  <div class="article-container">
    <article>
      <h5>Client:</h5>
      <p>Småtrollens föräldrakooperativ</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h5>Duration:</h5>
      <p>2 weeks</p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h5>Team:</h5>
      <p>Isabelle, Rebecca, Måns & Pontus</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `display: block` is the default for `article`, and you'll want to replace `align-items` with `text-align`